# Kernel space fcntl() equivalent

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

I’ve been learning a bit more about LKMs, and I was trying to use `fcntl()` in this space to get flags associated with a file descriptor. But since this is in kernel space, I assumed we could use `sys_fcntl()`. When I try this, it says that symbol is undefined.

Is this symbol not exported, or is there another call I should use to get flags (`O_CREAT`, `O_TMPFILE`, etc.)? I only have the file descriptor, which is why I thought `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For many linux kernel syscalls, (e.g.) `sys_fcntl` the internal/callable is `do_fcntl`. But, if you're in the kernel, given a pointer to a file struct, you can access the info directly off the pointer. In `do_fcntl`, it is passed `struct file *filp`. For `F_GETFL`, it returns `filp->f_flags` FYI, `do_fcntl` is in `fs/fcntl.c`, so you can use that as a model. You should convert the file descriptor (an `int`) into the pointer at the outer function and use the pointer internally.

Comment: @CraigEstey you should just copy paste that into an answer!